# How can I show child products in layered navigation if they aren't otherwise visible?

Tags: php, magento

Running Magento 1.9, i have a few hundred simple products that are a part of a configurable. These products are not visible individually. I have several attributes assigned to the simple products.

I want to use these attributes for layered navigation, but since the products aren't visible individually the layered navigation results only show the configurable.

Is it possible to have products otherwise not visible appear when filtered in layered navigation?

Am I taking the right approach to this?

For example, i have a t-shirt configurable and it's options are red, blue, green / small, med, large.

In the catalog it shows the configurable.

In layered navigation i would like to have red, blue, green / small, med, large that shows the simple products when applied. Instead it only just shows configurable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using a different approach.

First, I created sub-categories for each child product type and moved the respective products into the subcategory.

For example,

Clothing -> T-shirt

Clothing -> Pants

I moved the configurable into a different, new category and the child products in the t-shirt and pants category.

Then, I changed the clothing category to "Static Block Only" and show the configurables in a static block.

This keeps the configurables showing in a static block and keeps the layered navigation for simple products.

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but it's working as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose `Filterable(no results)` for `Use In Layered Navigation` for that color attribute which is used while creating configurable products.

[image]

Edit the color attibute and choose `Filterable(no results)` for the field `Use In Layered Navigation` and save it.

Clear cache and try.

I hope this will be useful.

Cheers :-)

Comment: That doesn't seem to achieve what I am after. When set to filterable (no results) it still shows every child product when they are set to visibility (catalog, search) and the attribute filter disappears if they are set to any other option (not visible or search only).